# How to create directive that removes other directives before they happen in Angular

Tags: css, angular, attributes, directive, angular2-directives

I am trying to make a directive that will prevent another directive from firing. I have tried to use both a structural and non structural directive to accomplish this and none of them have worked.

The simple html I am using:

```
<p appRemover appColor>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

Let's say I have a color-directive that just changes the color attribute of the element it is applied to to red. This is the code for the color directive:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.color = 'red'
  }
```

I will make another directive, the remover-directive, which will do the following:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private ren: Renderer2) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.ren.removeAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'appColor');
  }
```

the idea here is that I could simply remove the directive from the element before it is rendered. After printing the el.nativeElement after the removal of the appColor attribute it looks like the attribute is gone, but the color has already been changed to red. Ideally the remover directive would fire before the color directive but I can't seem to find out how Angular chooses the order.

I even tried a structural directive to take care of this:

```
constructor(private vc: ViewContainerRef, private template: TemplateRef<any>, private ren: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ren.removeAttribute(this.template.elementRef.nativeElement, 'appColor');
    this.vc.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
  }
```

but that actually throws an error saying that el.removeAttribute is not a function?

Is there an established pattern to be used to use a directive to remove or stop another directive on the same element to fire? If not, is there any way to actually do this?

Comment: Why would you do that? Why can't you let your `appColor` decide to do sth upon some condition?

Comment: the directive im trying to conditionally render is in an imported library so I cannot make changes like this to it

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can't dynamically create/remove directives, no matter what ([Github Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785)). If it's imported library you need to fork it and make for example `@Input() disabled` to that directive, so when it is active it won't fire events (of course you need to do that logic too).

Comment: could this be achieved by making a new component that takes a boolean input on whether or not to show the directive, as well as a template, and the component will use an ngswitch to render just the template or the template with the directive on it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot remove a directive conditionally. What you can do instead, is to have two versions of the element, one with the directive and one without it, and select the appropriate element with `*ngIf... else`. To avoid repeating the inner content of the elements, declare that content in a common template which is then inserted with an `ngTemplateOutlet`.

```html
<!-- Container element with the appColor directive -->
<p *ngIf="useColorDirective; else noColorDirective" appColor>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
</p>

<!-- Alternate container element, without the directive -->
<ng-template #noColorDirective>
  <p><ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container></p>
</ng-template>

<!-- Common content of the container elements -->
<ng-template #content>
  The inner content is here...
</ng-template>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clu3rh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

---

If you want to reuse that technique in several places, you can wrap the code in a component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-p',
  ...
})
export class AppParagraphComponent {
  @Input() useColor = true;
}
```

```html
<p *ngIf="useColor; else noColorDirective" appColor>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
</p>
<ng-template #noColorDirective>
  <p><ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container></p>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

which can then be used as:

```html
<app-p [useColor]="useColorDirective">
  This is the content!!!
</app-p>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clu3rh-8x9xjh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-paragraph.component.html) for a demo. You would probably need to have a define a different component for each type of element on which the color directive can be conditionally applied.

Comment: this seems like a great solution except that the directive im trying to conditionally change can be on elements other than just <p>s. Isnt there some idea of content projection i could combine this solution with to get at what i want?

Comment: I added to the answer an example of the code wrapped in a component. You may need to define several of them however, one for each element type.